# How can I create a schema with JOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am trying to create a Vertica table with [JOOQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JOOQ_Object_Oriented_Querying) 3.5.x:

```
Connection connection = create();
DSLContext dslContext = DSL.using(connection);
Field<String> myColumn = DSL.field("my_column", SQLDataType.VARCHAR);
Table table = DSL.tableByName("my_schema", "my_table");
dslContext.createTable(table)
        .column(myColumn, myColumn.getDataType())
        .execute();
```

This fails on *Schema "my_schema" does not exist*.

I can solve it with:

```
dslContext.execute("create schema if not exists my_schema");
```

But is there a more elegant way to create a schema with JOOQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently JOOQ covers just a subset of the possible [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements that can be executed against a server and schema management is not yet included so you have to drop back to plan old SQL.

If you need to do a lot of DDL work you should start to look at the latest version 3.8 as this has extend the capabilities to include

- DEFAULT column values in CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE statements
- IF EXISTS in DROP statements
- IF NOT EXISTS in CREATE statements
- ALTER TABLE .. { RENAME | RENAME COLUMN | RENAME CONSTRAINT } statements

Version 3.6 added

- ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT (with UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY, FOREIGN KEY, CHECK)
- ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT
- CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE

Comment: Just as a follow up, release 3.9 adds the following 

- A variety of RENAME statements
- The { CREATE | ALTER | DROP } SCHEMA statements
- The useful IF EXISTS clause for ALTER and DROP statements
- The useful IF NOT EXISTS clause for CREATE statements
- Support for partial indexes (CREATE INDEX .. WHERE)
- Support for ASC | DESC ordering in CREATE INDEX statements
- Support for Oracle's CONSTRAINT .. USING INDEX .. clause
- Support for IDENTITY columns
- Better support for constraint construction